# Escape triple quote within kotlin raw string

Tags: string, kotlin

I'm trying to create a raw string that contains three quotes in itself.

The resulting string x should contain something like `"""abc"""`.
I've been able to create the string with the following code, but was wondering if there's a simpler solution for this.

```kotlin
val x = """${'"'.toString().repeat(3)}abc${'"'.toString().repeat(3)}"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy way to use a triple quote directly in a string literal.

One workaround I've sometimes used is to make an interim variable to hold the triple-quote string.

```kotlin
val quotes = "\"\"\""
val result = "${quotes}abc${quotes}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way would be to escape them manually, so like:

```
val x = "\"\"\"abc\"\"\""
```